# After installation, `docker info` is not working

Tags: windows, docker, chocolatey, docker-toolbox

I installed Dock via `chocolatey install docker-toolbox`. After installation, `docker info` is not working.

```
C:\Users\Chloe>docker info
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/info: open 
//./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration 
on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the 
docker daemon is not running.

C:\Users\Chloe>docker --version
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
```

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#test-docker-version

I did run it from an Administrator shell.

Windows 8.1.

Comment: **Docker for Windows** would be a better choice.

Comment: @KitHsu That requires Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Had to run Start > Programs > Docker > Docker Quickstart Terminal which ran a lot of commands. Then in my original Console2 shell, I ran `refreshenv`. Then `docker info` would work. (I already had VirtualBox installed (`choco install virtualbox`).)